# node.js pm2 on exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I'm using pm2 to running node application. I must save data before application will be closed. This code works fine in shell:

```
process.on('exit', function(){
    log.debug('exit');
});

process.on('SIGINT', function(){
    log.debug('SIGINT');
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function(){
    log.debug('uncaughtException');
});
```

When I'm stopping the application using "pm2 stop" the code doesn't work. I think that pm2 kills process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SIGINT` is generally triggered after a user-invoked shutdown (e.g. Ctrl+C). Assuming `pm2` is triggering an *abrupt* shutdown then `SIGINT` won't be triggered.

Instead, you should listen for the termination signal `SIGTERM` which should cover both scenarios

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
    // clean up
});
```